# How to get train set just by specifying test set in R-programming?

Tags: r, sample

```
testpc <- 0.10
test <- sample_frac(Boston, testpc)
```

I want to get `train` without having to do:

```
trainpc <- 0.90
train <- sample_frac(Boston, trainpc)
```

I tried `Boston[-test]` but gives error.

Help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
# Using dplyr::sample_frac as implied in the question
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)
testpc <- 0.10
test <- sample_frac(Boston, testpc)
train <- Boston[!(rownames(Boston) %in% rownames(test)),]

# Wihtout using dplyr
library(MASS)
testpc <- 0.10 * nrow(Boston)
intest <- sample(1:nrow(Boston), testpc)
test <- Boston[intest,]
train <- Boston[-intest,]
```

Comment: do u know if it is possible to use  Boston[-test] or sth like that ?

Comment: @piya you cannot subset a `data.frame` with a `data.frame` (which is what `sample_frac` returns.  I have, however, updated my answer with something similar to `Boston[-test,]`.  In this case I am subsetting with an integer vector.